# Query on multiple range of document

Tags: elasticsearch

What I want to search is to extract documents among certain range of documents, not the whole documents. I know ids of documents. For example, I want to query matching some sentences with query field - 'pLabel' among the documents ids of which I know via different process. My trial is as below but I got bunch of documents which is different with my expectation.
For example, in such documents as eid1, eid2...etc groups, I want to query filtering out the matching documents out of the groups (eid1, eid2, eid3, ...). Query is shown as below.

How I fix query statement to get the right search result?

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "pLabel" ,
            "query": "search words here"
          }
        }
      ] ,
      "must_not": [] ,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "eid": "eid1"
          }
        } ,
        {
          "term": {
            "eid": "eid2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } ,
  "size": 0 ,
  "_source": [
    "eid"
  ] ,
  "aggs": {
    "eids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eid" ,
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand. do you have IDs of documents and want to return all documents?

Comment: I have ids of documents, and among the documents, I want to extract maching documents with my query in a certain field - 'pLabel'

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `should` clause of the Doc IDs inside the must clause.

Right now the query can return any document that matches the `query_string` clause, it'll only prefer docs that matches the Doc IDs.

Also, you should use `terms` query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "pLabel",
            "query": "search words here"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "user": ["eid1", "eid2"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": [
    "eid"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "eids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "eid",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```